# Easy way to fade the background color of a div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, fadeout

When a field is modified I want to highlight the background color of the `<div>` for that row.  Then slowly fade it back to normal.  So I use jQuery and jQuery UI's color animation effect:

```
$('.example_row')
    .css('backgroundColor', '#ff7f0')
    .animate({backgroundColor: '#d4d4d4'}, 5000)
    .html(modifiedContent);
```

The problem is the overall background is not `#d4d4d4`, it's a gradient.  So ideally I would just change the background opacity from 1 to 0 for the `<div>` for that row.  How do I do this?  I tried jQuery UI's removeClass effect:

```
$('.example_row')
    .addClass('modified')
    .removeClass('modified', 5000)
    .html(modifiedContent);
```

.modified just has the 1 css rule of `background-color: #ff7f00`.
The problem here is that removing the class means the background fades to solid white until the class if fully removed, then suddenly it changes to the true background gradient.  Looks bad...

So I know that I could simply inject a new `<div>` with a 100% width and height within the `<div>` for that row and do a simple `.animate({opacity: 0})`.  But I don't want to do that for other reasons... is there a simple solution here that doesn't require injecting an extra background `<div>`?

***UPDATE***: I created an [example of my situation](http://jsfiddle.net/avZxb/1/) on jsfiddle for a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A highlight effect already exist in UI,

```
$('input').focus(function(){
$(this).parent().effect("highlight", {},  1000);
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/9YWWw/1/

Comment: this is the correct answer except the effect should be applied to $(this).parent() if the DIV needs to be highlighted not the field

Comment: Uh, I was referring to the input itself. If the div and not the input needs to be highlighted when input is focused, then using parent() will do it. `$(this).parent().effect("highlight", {},  1000);`. I updated the answer

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!  What possible options can I use?  I assume I can change the highlight color?  The documentation on jQuery UI's site doesn't mention what the options are...

Comment: Oh no, this doesn't actually work unfortunately :(.  Maybe I need some option set, but it simply highlights the row and then fades it to WHITE...  looks bad on a gradient background..

Comment: Also, the effect is very short-lived... I need it highlighted longer.  The "1000" speed isn't the speed of the effect, it's the length of time it stays in the unfortunate WHITE end-state.  I'm surprised this came out of the normally high quality jQuery UI project.

Comment: @Hussein, as outlined in the question I was already able to easily get a much better highlight effect, the whole issue here was that I couldn't get the highlight to fade properly with a gradient background

Comment: that's not dealing with a gradient background behind the div

Comment: Where's the gradient background, I don't see it anywhere in your code. You need to post a jsfiddle example.

Comment: In @Hussein's example, try replacing the color #ffffff instances with transparent. That way it will fade from transparent to grey and back to transparent

Comment: @Hussein, I updated the question with a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/avZxb/1/.

@Dan, that doesn't work.  jQuery UI's animate function apparently doesn't work well with backgroundColor: transparent

Comment: @at Gradient property works different for every browser. The only  direct solution i have is to use a gradient image instead of gradient css properties. This will ensure cross browser support and smooth animation of the gradient. You can also try some of the jQuery gradient plugins and see if that solves your issue.